# NSOperationQueue run same task again on response iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

In my project I need to send data to server, for that I've used the following code to achieve the task:

```
- (void)sendJSONToServer:(NSString *) jsonString
{
// Create a new NSOperationQueue instance.
operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
//

// Create a new NSOperation object using the NSInvocationOperation subclass to run the operationQueueTask method
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                        selector:@selector(operationQueueTask:)
                                                                        object:jsonString];
// Add the operation to the queue and let it to be executed.
[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
}//End of sendJSONToServer method

-(void) operationQueueTask:(NSString *) jsonString
{
//NSOperationQueue *remoteResultQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SERVER_QUEUE",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Performing long running process
    // Sending json data to server asynchronously
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonString length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL_eg_http://www.example.com"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Response is:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
     }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Update the UI
        NSLog(@"Thread Process Finished");
    });
});
}//End of operationQueueTask method
```

By the above code I'm able to send data and get response.

But when there is no internet the data will not be sent to server. How to handle this situation based on the response we get.

Let's say we get response `success` on fair condition ans `false` on worst condition.

---

**UPDATED CODE FOR RETRIES**

```
-(id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil)
{
    //initialize stuffs here
    pendingOperationQueue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
}
return self;
}//End of init method

- (void)sendJSONToServer:(NSString *) jsonString
{
    NSOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(operationQueueTask:) object:[NSString stringWithString:[pendingOperationQueue objectAtIndex:0]]];
[operation start];
}//End of sendJSONToServer method

-(void) operationQueueTask:(NSString *) jsonString
{
//NSOperationQueue *remoteResultQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SERVER_QUEUE",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Performing long running process
    // Sending json data to server asynchronously
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonString length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL_http://www/example.com"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Response is:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);

         if([[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] rangeOfString:@"true"].location == NSNotFound)
         {
             // Add the operation to the queue and let it to be executed.
             NSLog(@"Failed To Add To Server, Rerunning the task");
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Successfully Added To Server");
             NSLog(@"ADDED_DATA_TO_SERVER: %@", jsonString);
             if([pendingOperationQueue count] > 0)
             {
                 [pendingOperationQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];

                 if([pendingOperationQueue count] > 0)
                 {
                     NSOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(operationQueueTask:) object:[NSString stringWithString:[pendingOperationQueue objectAtIndex:0]]];
                     [operation start];
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
});
}//End of operationQueueTask method
```

Answer (score 6):

**Heads up! This is a long answer.** *TL;DR: You can't re-run an `NSOperation`, but you can design your classes and methods to make it easy to retry requests.*

---

First a quick answer to your title question: you can't re-run an `NSOperation`, they're not designed to do that. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/):

> An operation object is a single-shot object — that is, it executes its
>   task once and cannot be used to execute it again.

With that out of the way, lets take a look at what you're currently doing and clean it up a bit so that re-using it is easier. There's a ton of async stuff going on in there that you don't need; I'll go through it piece by piece.

Let's start with your `operationQueueTask:` method. The first thing you do in the method is:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("SERVER_QUEUE",NULL);
```

That means that every time that method is called, you're creating a new dispatch queue. While you can do that if you really want to, that's not what dispatch queues are really designed for. A better idea would be to use one of the background queues that are already available:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
```

Next you are dispatching a block asynchronously to that queue. That block:

1. Sets up your `NSMutableURLRequest`.
2. Calls `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...]`.
3. Dispatches another block (which has a comment in it about updating the UI) to the main queue.

1 and 2 are fine, I don't see anything you need to change there. 3, however, is problematic because of where that dispatch is being called. The way you have it setup now, `NSURLConnection` will fire off its asynchronous request and then, before that even has a chance to run, you fire off the block to the main queue to update the UI. What you need to do instead is fire off that block in the completion handler passed to `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...]`. Like so:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"Response is:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         // Update the UI
         NSLog(@"Thread Process Finished");
     });
 }];
```

Now, notice the name of the method you're calling on `NSURLConnection`? `send`**`Asynchronous`**`Request:`. It actually handles queuing the request on a background queue for you. Which mean, you don't actually need (or want) all the `dispatch_*` stuff at the beginning of this method. With that in mind, we can reduce it down to:

```
-(void) operationQueueTask:(NSString *) jsonString
{
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonString length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL_eg_http://www.example.com"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Response is:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // Update the UI
             NSLog(@"Thread Process Finished");
         });
     }];
} //End of operationQueueTask method
```

Now, on to your `sendJSONToServer:` method. You're doing a similar thing here that you did at the start of `operationQueueTask:`: you're creating a new `NSOperationQueue` each time it runs; that's also not needed (nor typically wanted). What you should probably be doing is creating that `operationQueue` when your class is initialized (it looks like it's already an instance variable on your class, so you're good there):

```
// NOTE: I'm just using a default initializer here; if you already have an initializer, use that instead
- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

That gets rid of your first line. Next, you're creating an `NSInvocationOperation` which calls `operationQueueTask:` and then adding it to your `operationQueue`. Since you've been re-creating your `operationQueue` every time, I'm going to assume that it isn't used for anything other than these server requests. In that case, you actually don't need to do this on your `operationQueue` at all because, as we discovered in the previous method, `NSURLConnection` is already handling all the background threading for you.  In *that* case, we can actually just copy the code from `operationQueueTask:` to `sendJSONToServer:` and get rid of `operationQueueTask:` altogether. That makes it look like:

```
- (void)sendJSONToServer:(NSString*)jsonString {
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonString length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL_eg_http://www.example.com"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:operationQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Response is:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             // Update the UI
             NSLog(@"Thread Process Finished");
         });
     }];
}
```

***Note:** We still need to keep `operationQueue` around since we pass it to `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:...` as the queue that it should run on.*

So, how do we go about retrying the request when it fails? The simplest method is to add a recursive function that calls itself when the request fails. You'll pass this method the `jsonString` you want to send and the maximum number of times it should try to send it before it gives up for good.

To facilitate that, lets make one more change to you existing function: instead of handling the completion block inside the function, lets make the completion block a parameter you pass to the function so that it can be processed elsewhere.

```
- (void)sendJSONToServer:(NSString*)jsonString withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError))completionHandler {
    NSData *postData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonString length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"MY_URL_eg_http://www.example.com"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:operationQueue completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Now, lets build that recursive function. I'll call it:

```
- (void)sendJSONToServer:(NSString*)jsonString withRetryAttempts:(NSUInteger)retryTimes;
```

The basic flow will be:

1. Check if `retryTimes` is greater than 0
2. If it is, attempt to send the request to the server
3. When the request finishes, check the response for success
4. If successful, update the UI on the main queue
5. If not successful, subtract one from `retryTimes` and call this function again

That looks something like:

```
- (void)sendJSONToServer:(NSString*)jsonString withRetryAttempts:(NSUInteger)retryTimes {
    if (retryTimes > 0) {
        [self sendJSONToServer:jsonString withCompletionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Response is:%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
            if (/* check response to make sure it succeeded */) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Update the UI
                    NSLog(@"Thread Process Finished");
                });
            } else {
                // Note: you can add a dispatch_after here (or something similar) to wait before the next attempt
                // You could also add exponential backoff here, which is usually good when retrying network stuff
                [self sendJSONToServer:jsonString withRetryAttempts:(retryTimes - 1)];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        // We're out of retries; handle appropriately
    }
}
```

***Note:** There are some bits in there that are just comments because they are application specific; they'll need to be implemented before that code will compile/run.*

Now, instead of calling `[yourClass sendJSONToServer:jsonString]`, call: `[yourClass sendJSONToServer:jsonString withRetryTimes:maxRetries]` and, if the request fails, it should retry up to `maxRetries` times.

***One last note:** As @Deftsoft mentioned, Apple's Reachability classes are a nice way to know if you have an active connection to the network or not. It's a good idea to check that first before trying to call `sendJSONToServer:withRetryTimes:`. That way you're not trying to make requests when it's not possible to even connect in the first place.*

Comment: +1 for a brief answer, and thanks for your time in answering, I learnt so many stuffs from your answer, but unfortunately if we keep retrying at some point we have to stop even if the result is failure or if we keep retrying for a longer duration it won't be good right ? Please comment for suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: What you do if all your reties fail is very app specific, but one thing that's done a lot is to store the json you were sending somewhere (typically to a file) and then try to send it again when some condition changes (something like the app restarting, or the network changes).

Comment: that's a great idea, I want to share my updated code for retries which I've been working on, if you don't mind please take a look at it, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: A couple of quick observations: 1. I don't see where you are adding anything to `pendingOperationQueue`.  2. I don't see where you are calling`sendJSONToServer` to trigger the retry.

Answer (score 0):

You can Apple reachability classes below is the reference code which will provide you the better idea.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(networkChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

        reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        [reachability startNotifier];

        - (void)networkChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
        {

          NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

          if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable) { NSLog(@"not reachable");}
          else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFiNetwork) { NSLog(@"wifi"); }
          else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaCarrierDataNetwork) { NSLog(@"carrier"); }
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, it's really good,, but my question is how to re-run the operations, not to check network change status, please let us know about that riddle.